# What happens if I use accessibilityIdentifier and accessibilityLabel on same element

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

What happens if I use an accessibilityIdentifier and an accessibilityLabel on same element?  Will one override the other, will it still be accessible to a disabled user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessibility identifiers are for only automation testing. They are not helpful for users/developers. You can use accessibility label/hint. Even if you set them both, they will not be overridden.

Comment: Unless you work in an organisation, I suggest you not to use accessibility identifier. There is not much use of them!!!

Comment: Thanks, I am adding Accessibility Identifiers to make my app testable through automation, and want to make sure if I have an accessibility label and identifier on the same element, that a disabled user will still be able to use the app feature via the accessibility label

Comment: Yes, the element is still accessible in that case.And it doenst over ride

Comment: Also I do work in an organization! we are making it so we can automate the testing of our app. we are mostly manual now